# semantics invocation RPC to use

Tags: rpc, semantics

Imagining the scenario of voting at an election. And a client call a rpc method to vote, which would be the best to use semantics, maybe, at-least-once or at-most-once?

I think it depends on the implementation of the method, since the method is idempotent then can be at-least-once, that is, if you vote once and vote again on the same person, is not an issue in this case can be at-least -once, but if I try to change my vote since I can not, so at-most-once, it was the best option. Still a bit confused semantics ...

But following the logic that sending multiple votes, ie, relay the message always has to be worth only a vote. The conclusion I draw is that the method is idempotent then uses-at-least-once. I am thinking right?

Thank you for your attention